# Does sum of embeddings make sense?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, recommender-system, embeddings

Referring to the LightFM model from paper [Metadata Embeddings for User and Item Cold-start Recommendations](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.08439.pdf), the  model tries to learn $d$-dimensional user and item feature embeddings $e_f^U$ and $e_f^I$ for each feature $f$ ($U$ is the set of users, $I$ is the set of items).

The latent representation of user $u$ is given by the sum of its features' latent vectors:
$$
\mathbf{q_u} = \sum_{j\in{f_u}}\mathbf{e_j^U}
$$

The same holds for item $i$:
$$
\mathbf{p_i} = \sum_{j\in{f_i}}\mathbf{e_j^I}
$$

Does it really make sense to sum the latent embeddings to represent a set of features (user or item)?

Answer (score 1):

Thinking of a sum as an average, this model sounds reminiscent of continuous bag of words (CBOW) word embeddings (i.e. word2vec). In that context, the words in a sentence are used to predict a missing word using the average of embedded vectors (see this [question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9785/predicting-a-word-using-word2vec-model/10417)). This method works pretty well for words, so it might make sense that you could extend it to other types of embeddings like user/item compatibility.

The average makes some intuitive sense when you think of comparisons. To place a user/item in embedding space, you can average the feature embeddings. If a user/item has different but similar features their average should put the user/item in a similar region of embedding space. A sum should work the same if the feature number is fixed.

An issue with a sum would arise if feature number isn't fixed. Users/items could appear different because their embedding vector is a different length, even if it has the same direction. Normalizing by feature number would fix this.

Another possible issue with using a sum rather than an average is that the user/item embedded vectors aren't comparable to the feature embedded vectors. This doesn't seem to matter for the author, because they don't try to compare the user/item vectors to the feature vectors directly.

TL;DR Yes, a sum might make sense to represent a set of features, but an average might be better.

Answer (score 0):

Summing Embeddings can makes sense under certain conditions.

If you want to just do a naive **euclidian distance** based k-NN to find close samples, summing the vectors **doesn't work** because the tip of the vector gets moved away from the origin.

This is easy to visualize if you add the same vector to itself (or scale it with a factor of 2), there will be a new euclidian distance to it's un-summed version that is equal to its own magnitude.

But there are other metrics where this does make sense like the **cosine distance**.

As this only looks at the relative angle between the vectors, the magnitude of the vectors doesn't influence the result. So a scaled vector will still give you a cosine distance of 1 to it's unscaled variant.